# Does "return;" at the end of a void method in Java have ANY impact on performance?

Tags: java, methods, void

This may sound like a stupid question, but I'll figure that out soon. Anyways, if I were to add `return;` to the end of a void method in Java, would there be any (and I mean ANY) impact on performance? For example:

Original method:

```
public void method(){
   int i = 1;
}
```

New method:

```
public void method(){

   int i = 1;
   return;
}
```

Now, obviously this doesn't have any SIGNIFICANT impact on the program's performance, but will it have an insignificant imapct? And if it doesn't change performance in any way, does it change anything else? (Like the size of the compiled program?)

Comment: performance questions are actually related to http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @TilakMaddy Ah, ok. I saw a few performance questions on this site so ,i decided to ask my own, but I will remember that for next time. Thanks.

Comment: @TilakMaddy Since this is trivial toy code, I don't think this would be considered ontopic there.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

If you mean runtime performance, no; The bytecode emitted by the compiler is identical with and without it. This is easy to check: Compile it with, use `javac -p ClassName` to see the decompiled version, then compile it with, and do the same. You'll find they're identical (both have the `return` bytecode in them).

> And if it doesn't change performance in any way, does it change anything else? (Like the size of the compiled program?)

Nope. The bytecode is identical, as is the size.

Answer (score 5):

Actually, if you have a void method without any return statement, the compiler will always generate a return instruction at the end of it. So I think it changes nothing at all.